# SwiftUI multi window Mac app state restoration

Tags: swiftui, multi-window, ios-state-restoration

When we open multiple windows in our app, kill the app, and relaunch it, shouldn't the previously opened windows pop automatically based on state restoration principles?

Here is my main:

```
@main
struct WindowTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        WindowGroup("Title", for: Person.ID.self){ $id in
            TestView(personID: $id)
        }
    }
}
```

My window open button:

```
struct OpenWindowButton: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow
    let person: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open new window"){
            openWindow(value: person.id)
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
struct Person:Identifiable, Hashable{
    
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    var id: UUID
}

let people:[Person] = [
    Person(name: "Jack", age: 41, id: UUID()),
    Person(name: "Mary", age: 32, id: UUID()),
    Person(name: "Linda", age: 18, id: UUID()),
    Person(name: "Joe", age: 13, id: UUID()),
    Person(name: "Kid", age: 1, id: UUID())
]
```

My ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(people, id:\.self){person in
                VStack{
                    Text(person.name)
                }.contextMenu{
                    OpenWindowButton(person: person)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My TestView

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var personID: Person.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let personFromID = people.first(where: {$0.id == personID}){
            VStack {
                Text(personFromID.name)
                Text("\(personFromID.age)")
            }
        }else{
            Text("no person for you")
        }
    }
}
```

So, according to the documentation, SwiftUI should enable state restoration based on the binding value passed to the view. But when I relaunch the app, the popped windows show 'no person for you' instead of previously populated person info.

Any ideas are muchly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a link to the relevant portion of the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: I doubt that any state restoration will work correctly if you "kill" the app, as in stopping it from the debugger (Xcode). When testing state restoration, UserDefaults, AppStorage etc. usually QUIT your app instead of killing it to get valid results.

Comment: I put your code in a fresh project and tried it. Each `WindowGroup` stores its last size and position. That's it. Nothing unexpected, because you are not storing `people`, initialize each time with a new `UUID`. Something must be different in your real code because you see 'no person for you'.